# How to remove records from a dataset with LINQ

Tags: linq, dataset

I have a dataset (called dataSet below) with a single table and some records in it. One of the columns is called Message and contains an error message. If any records have a value in this field I want to copy it into an error dataset (errorDataSet below) and then remove it from the original dataset. I managed to get this far with LINQ:

```
        DataSet errorDataSet = dataSet.Copy();

        //find all records that have a Message column value
        var query = from row in errorDataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                    where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Field<string>("Message"))
                    select row;

        DataSet tempErrorDataSet = errorDataSet.Clone();
        foreach (var row in query)
        {
            tempErrorDataSet.Tables[0].Clear();
            tempErrorDataSet.Tables[0].ImportRow(row);
            utility.WriteError(connectorName, row["Message"].ToString(), tempErrorDataSet);

            //remove the error row from the good data
            dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Remove(row);
        }
```

The bottom line throws an exception or I get errors regarding modifying a collection etc. I'm sure there is a simple way of doing this in LINQ.

Note: The reason I have tempErrorDataSet is that I convert it to XML and pass it into a stored proc - it only takes a record at a time in that format, hence I clear it each time.

Comment: What is the error, exception etc that you get?

Comment: The exception about removing an item from a collection, however I want to rewrite this code completely using LINQ, as per my question (it's not about the exception)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is enumerating (indirectly) through the rows in the table.  As you should already know, you cannot modify a collection (remove something in this case) as you enumerate over it.  Throw the contents into a list beforehand.  That way you're not enumerating through the actual table but a copy of some rows.

```
var query = (from row in errorDataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
             where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Field<string>("Message"))
             select row).ToList();
```

Comment: p.s., I believe you want to clear the temp table _before_ the loop, not within it.